# How do I use symbols as keys

Tags: typescript

I want to do this

```
interface test {
  [k: symbol]: (e: string) => void;
}
const S = Symbol()

const obj: test = { [S]: (data) => { console.log(data)  } }
```

Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)

I expected "data" to be a string,What did I get wrong?

Comment: @Terry I believe you can post an answer to this question

Comment: const S = Symbol() // typeof S
let S = Symbol() // symbol
I'd like to hear someone to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work around and see that:

```js
const S = Symbol() // S will be "typeof S" not a symbol
```

If you change S to

```js
const S: symbol = Symbol() // S will be a symbol
// OR
let S = Symbol() // S will be a symbol
```

, your code will works.

I think Typescript team already implement it to solve issues. I'm waiting for some explaination.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAkgZzMg3gWAFDLIDaA1gFzJoCeAtgEYD2ANgLoUAUEFGUoA5gEpkAXgB8yAG4NgAEwDc%20AL758CBiAzIAyt1qMmI7XubshAejOoqABxRjKxpqvWatARkNbHp5Bau2RcTAbCAYYbTd8JghMLQAmT29zS2CA%202p6ZhU8NQ1MBjoAKwp0TGFsYi02ZHYZODA4IXssZFy0ZggAOiYGPlr6xsJFZGUcl3yihPKWoiqOOobuMF4QQUCKto7u3v6GoRGR5zzkAC9DAsK42ZYgA)